# JavaScript is displaying an incorrect mathematical answer

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I wrote this small script that would calculate a students GPA. I decided to test it midway and it appears as if the code messes up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GPA Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id="varA">
    <input type="text" id="varB">
    <input type="text" id="varC">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNumbers('varA', 'varB', 'varC')"></input>
    <h1 id="testResult"></h1>
    <script>
            function addNumbers(elem1, elem2, elem3) {
            var a = document.getElementById(elem1).value;
            if (a == 90){
            a = 4
            }
            var b = document.getElementById(elem2).value;
            var c = Number(a) + Number(b);
            c = c / 8
            document.getElementById("testResult").innerHTML = c;
}
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example if I add 2 and 2 and 12 instead of displaying 2 it displays 1.75 which is weird.

Comment: Why is that weird when you are dividing c by 8 and you never process the content of elem3?

Comment: You're diving by 8 not 2

Comment: `(2 + 2) / 8 = 0.5` - How are you getting `1.75`? Are you missing some code from the example? Also, `varC` or `elem3` is never used in the sample code. Is that missing part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the third values so you get wrong results.
If you inputs 2,2,12 result is **0.5**, because of (2+2)/8 = 4/8 = 0.5.
For 2,12,2 or 12,2,2 result is **1,75** because of (2+12)/8 = 14/8 = 1,75

This should give you the desired result.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>GPA Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id="varA">
    <input type="text" id="varB">
    <input type="text" id="varC">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addNumbers('varA', 'varB', 'varC')">
    <h1 id="testResult"></h1>
    <script>
            function addNumbers(elem1, elem2, elem3) {
            var a = document.getElementById(elem1).value;
            if (a == 90){
            a = 4
            }
            var b = document.getElementById(elem2).value;
            var c = document.getElementById(elem3).value;
            let sum = Number(a) + Number(b) + Number(c);
            let result = sum / 8;
            document.getElementById("testResult").innerHTML = result;
}
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Sorry I'm new at this whole javascript thing it's my first time ever making one